# Why did Thor get himself captured?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-ragnarok

In the beginning of *Thor: Ragnarok*, Thor said:

> Well, sometimes you have to get captured just to get a straight answer out of something.

What exactly did he want to find out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thor wanted to find out more about the Ragnarok prophecy. And, he succeeded in doing so.

> Surtur told him that when his crown would be put inside *Eternal Flame*, he would grow bigger than a mountain to destroy Asgard. Thor used this information to knock Surtur's crown out of his head so that it could never be put into the *Eternal Flame*.

Comment: It's also an OoU joke about the bad guys telling the good guys their plans when they have the good guy captured I reckon.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Also, in-universe, it's the same technique Black Widow uses in *The Avengers*, albeit less subtly performed.